# Aptana show .htaccess files

Tags: editing, htaccess, aptana-studio

Using the new Aptana Studio 2.0 and loving it. Trying to open and edit .htaccess files in Aptana Studio, but it's not showing up in the PHP Explorer pane, which normally shows all files, but not .htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too.  I found this [solution](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/462-ftp-htaccess-files-not-visible#comment_533277):

> The ',' files are filtered by default. To make them visible, you could use the drop-down arrow on the File view toolbar, select Customize View, and then uncheck Filters->. files.

There is a setting in File View to hide .files as .htaccess

Also uncheck the .*resources filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the file in the project explorer and the select open with and then text editor.